# Sort names in ascending order in arrays in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, higher-order-functions

For example, when an array of names is given,

```js
let names = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Rachel'],
    ['age', 10],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Sam'],
    ['lastName', 'Smith'],
    ['age', 20],
    ['gender', 'male'],
  ],
];
```

The output should look like this following code.

```
let output = nameInOrder(names);
console.log(output); // --> ['Rachel', 'Sam Smith'];
```

In order for me to complete the function of nameInOrder,

```js
function nameInOrder(arr) {
// my code goes here
}
```

would it be right for me to begin with `.map` to change the form into objects in an array, `sort(a,b)` and `.map.join(' ')` ?
how would you sort them in ascending order?

Comment: Why not use objects instead of arrays to specify a person?

Comment: You'll want to transform your data with `.map` into strings, then sort those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` is in the right direction. You'll want to transform the data into strings, then sort on those.

```js
let people = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Rachel'],
    ['age', 10],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Sam'],
    ['lastName', 'Smith'],
    ['age', 20],
    ['gender', 'male'],
  ],
];

function nameInOrder(arr) {
  return arr.map(person => {
    const fields = person.map(entry => entry[0])
    if (fields.includes('firstName') && fields.includes('lastName')) {
      return [
        person.find(entry => entry[0] == 'firstName')[1],
        person.find(entry => entry[0] == 'lastName')[1],
      ].join(' ')
    } else if (fields.includes('firstName')) {
      return person.find(entry => entry[0] == 'firstName')[1]
    } else if (fields.includes('lastName')) {
      return person.find(entry => entry[1] == 'lastName')[1]
    } else {
      return ''
    }
  }).sort()
}

console.log(nameInOrder(people))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. would you care to kindly explain why I see this error message? ``` AssertionError: expected [ '', 'Mary Jenkins', 'Samuel' ] to deeply equal [ 'Samuel', 'Revees', 'Mary Jenkins' ]```

Comment: Added a case when a person only has a `'lastName'`

Comment: should I add another else if and place below ```AssertionError: expected [ '', 'Mary Jenkins', 'Samuel' ] to deeply equal [ 'Samuel', 'Revees', 'Mary Jenkins' ]``` ? 
``

Comment: I updated my original answer to handle the case for lastName (since I was already handling the default, figured I might as well). The updated snippet should pass those test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.sort()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

Define a function to compare the names which you pass to `.sort()`.

```js
names.sort((a,b) => {
  var nameA = a[0][1].toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b[0][1].toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
});
```

---

Please consider not formatting your data like this, please do something like:

```js
let names = [
  [
    { 'firstName': 'Rachel' },
    { 'age': 10 },
    { 'gender': 'female' }
  ]
];
```

In that case sorting would be similar, but at not dependent on the order of the attributes in your array of names.

```js
names.sort((a,b) => {
  var nameA = a.firstName.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.firstName.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: The array names is prefixed and I need to transform it into objects in an array... thank you for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

If the source data really can only be arrays.

```js
const names = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Rachel'],
    ['age', 10],
    ['gender', 'female'],
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Sam'],
    ['lastName', 'Smith'],
    ['age', 20],
    ['gender', 'male'],
  ],
];

const result = names.map(person => {
    const name = person.reduce((obj, [index, value]) => {
        obj[index] = value;
        return obj;
      }, {});
    return `${name.firstName || ''} ${name.lastName || ''}`.trim();
});

console.log (result);
```